# Can no longer load Developer package after upgrading to 13.2 from 13.1

Tags: packages

```
Needs["Developer`"]
```

returns `$Failed`
with message `Get::noopen cannot open Developer`.`

However, directly specifying the context to the symbol I want produces the expected result e.g.

```
Developer`$MaxMachineInteger
```

works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem persists after restarting the application?  Does ```FindFile["Developer`"]``` return a string or failure?

Comment: Works with v13.2 on my Mac. `Developer`$MaxMachineInteger` evaluates to `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Works. MMA version 13.2 on Windows 10.  `FindFile["Developer`"] ` returns:  ""D:\\P\\math13.2\\SystemFiles\\Kernel\\Packages\\Developer.m""

Comment: Aha. FindFile["Developer`"] results in $Failed.
However, C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Kernel\Packages\Developer.m exists when I check manually.
A problem with the default paths to search for?

Comment: I fixed the problem by resetting the configuration as outlined here
https://support.wolfram.com/12464
. Not ideal but it worked.